# setTimeout alert with a link hyperlink in it? coupon message pop up after 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, settimeout, alert

Is there any way to make the link in this setTimeout alert clickable?  I'm just trying to give visitors to my website 5% OFF link after spending 30 seconds on my website but I need the link to be clickable if possible.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){alert("Get 5% OFF at: mysite.com/5-OFF  ")},30000);
</script>
```

I don't have to accomplish this by setTimeout but I don't know of any other way.  Any help or suggestions much appreciated.  Here I seem to always get the best.

Comment: do they need to spend 30 seconds on one page? or can it be any where on the site? the solution with setTimeout will only work for one page. If this is acceptable, then you just have to pop up a div/dialog containing the information you want to give them.

Comment: While something like `setTimeout(function(){if (confirm("Want to get 5% OFF?")) location.href="/mysite.com/5-OFF"},30000);` would do the job, it would scare me away for good. Permanently.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can only display text in the alert function. If you want to put in a URL, you can do it by using [jQuery UI's dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default) or [Twitter Bootstrap's modal window](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) (for example).

**EDITED TO INCLUDE ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION**
Something along the lines of:

```
setTimeout(function() { $( "ELEMENT" ).dialog( "open" ); }, 30000);
```

Comment: Hey jQuery UI dialog looks like it would work but how do I make it appear after 30 seconds?

Comment: Edited answer with the answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

Use a UI Widget from one of the many widget libraries for this. Modern websites should not use the javascript alert **anywhere** , but perhaps for testing(maybe).